# G++ linking batch PATH

Tags: c++, batch-file, path, linker, g++

I have 2 different g++ compilers on my computer:

- one in the standard directory (C:\MinGW),
- and one is a portable distribution.

Now I'm trying to link a c++ project.

The problem is, it is linked against boost libraries
compiled with the portable distribution of g++. The standard
installation directory is ofcourse included in the `PATH` environment
variable. So when I try to compile my project it will produce linker errors.

I tried to create a batch file which added the portable version's directory at **the beginning** of the PATH variable. With no luck. Maybe some one can help me out?

```
@echo off
set PATH=%~dp0..\c++\compiler\bin;%PATH%

REM cd /d "%~dp0"

..\c++\compiler\bin\g++ main.cpp ^
-std=c++0x -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ ^
-I"../c++/include" ^
-L"../c++/lib" ^
-l"boost_serialization-mgw46-mt-1_52" ^
-l"boost_system-mgw46-mt-1_52" ^ 
-o output.exe -W -O2
pause
```

Note: I used "..\c++\compiler\bin\" befor the g++ command because I wanted to be sure it it used the right path, but ofcourse it doesn't work the way I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by recompiling boost with the installed version of GCC.